# mongodb not showing in phpinfo() for windows

Tags: php, mongodb

I am trying to connect MongoDB with my PHP, to use `new MongoClient()` I need configure "php_mongo.dll" in my php.ini file but after doing that MongoDB info is not showing in phpinfo.
versions I am using are:
PHP 5.5.30, MongoDB 5.2.10
DLL downloaded from "http://windows.php.net/downloads/pecl/releases/mongo/1.5.8/php_mongo-3.2.10-5.5-ts-vc11-x86.zip" and I have 32 bit machine.

Answer (score 0):

I´ve had the same problem in Windows 10 with Apache 2.4 and PHP 5.6. I tried the many version of mongo driver but nothing worked. Then I tried version 1.5 and all works fine now, the error on apache log has gone and MongoDB support are showed in phpinfo(). And another point is you have to start mongodb server for connection.

For more info you can check on official website.
https://docs.mongodb.com/ecosystem/drivers/php/

Comment: try to restart apache, php-fpm. Still not working than try to restart system. Some time it took changes after system restart